# Solving coupled langrangian derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been told that the solution to
$$\frac{Du}{Dt}=2\Omega v, \frac{Dv}{Dt}=-2\Omega u$$
is
$$u(t) = u_0 \cos2\Omega t+ v_0 \sin 2\Omega t$$
$$v(t) = -u_0 \sin 2\Omega t + v_0 \cos 2\Omega t$$
But how would I arrive at this solution by analysis?  Is there a method I can use, or is it simply a pattern I need to recognise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take the time derivative of the 2 equations.
\begin{align}
 \frac{d^2}{dt^2} u (t) &= 2\Omega \frac{dv(t)}{dt} = -4\Omega^2 u(t)\\
 \frac{d^2}{dt^2} v (t) &= -2\Omega \frac{du(t)}{dt} = -4\Omega^2 v(t)
\end{align}
i.e.
\begin{align}
 \frac{d^2}{dt^2} u (t) +4\Omega^2 u(t) = 0\\
 \frac{d^2}{dt^2} v (t) +4\Omega^2 v(t) =0
\end{align}
Then you solve for both, use the Euler identity to recover the cos/sin form. It can also be noted through chain derivatives that $du/dv=-v/u\implies u=-v$, which allows you to only solve for one of the above.

Comment: I'm feel stupid having to ask, but what technique do I use for solving for $u'' + 4\Omega^2u = 0$?

Comment: There is no stupid question. This is a standard order 2 ODE with linear coefficients. Use the Ansatz $u=e^{bt}$. You will find that this is a solution if $b=\pm 2i\Omega$. The general solution is therefore a linear superposition of both, i.e. $u(t)=Ae^{2i\Omega t}+Be^{-2i\Omega t}$. Initial condition are used to set the value of $A$ and $B$. With $e^{\pm ix} = \cos(x)\pm i\sin(x)$ you should recover the stated solution.

Comment: I hadn't heard of [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) before, I'm more willing to accept this having read about it, thanks!